# Error while executing Async Task

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, apache-commons-httpclient, background-thread

I m trying to get some data from a couple of web pages and saving it into a file. I'm doing all this in the `AsynkTask` in Android (doInBackground). When i run the app in my emulator... I get a runtime error: error occured while executing doInBackground`. I ran through the code a couple of times but can't seem to find out what's wrong. Here's my code below... Somebody pls help me!! Also pls let me know on how i can improve this code... Its really tedious as of now.

```
public class OpeningActivity extends Activity {

static final String PAGE_URL = "http://www.facebook.com/pages/Symbiosis-College-of-   Arts-Commerce-Confession/524808617560510";
static String title, imgSource, viewFormLink, viewFormEntry, formResponse, data;
static PrintWriter writer, formWriter, dfWriter;
static FileInputStream fis;
static File dataFile, confessionsPage, formFile;
Button setup;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_opening);
    setup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSetup);

    setup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new getWebPage().execute(PAGE_URL);
        }
    });
}


public class getWebPage extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

protected void onPreExecute(String f) {
    // TODO Setting up variables
    f = "whatevs";
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DefaultHttpClient urlClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet getHtml = new HttpGet(PAGE_URL);
    ResponseHandler<String> resHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    try {
        String htmlPage = urlClient.execute(getHtml, resHandler);
                    lod.d("htmlpage", htmplPage);
        confessionsPage = new File("ConfessionsPage.html");
        confessionsPage.createNewFile();
        writer = new PrintWriter(confessionsPage, "UTF-8");
        writer.print(htmlPage.replace("<!--", "").replace("-->", ""));
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(confessionsPage, "UTF-8", "http://www.facebook.com/");
        title = doc.title().substring(0, doc.title().length() - 11);

        Elements imgSRC = doc.select("img[src$=.jpg]");
        for (Element element : imgSRC) {
            if (element.attr("class").equals("profilePic img")) {
                imgSource = element.attr("src");
            }
        }

        Elements links = doc.select("a[href*=google]");
        viewFormLink = null;
        for (Element element : links) {
            viewFormLink = element.attr("href");
        }
        viewFormLink = viewFormLink.replace("http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=", "");
        int ampLOC = viewFormLink.indexOf("&");
        viewFormLink = viewFormLink.substring(0, ampLOC);
        viewFormLink = URLDecoder.decode(viewFormLink, "UTF-8");

        formResponse = viewFormLink.substring(0, (viewFormLink.length() - 8));
        formResponse = formResponse + "formResponse";
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    DefaultHttpClient formClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet getForm = new HttpGet(viewFormLink);
    ResponseHandler<String> resHandler2 = new BasicResponseHandler();

    try {
        String formPage = formClient.execute(getForm, resHandler2);
        formFile = new File("FormPage.html");
        formFile.createNewFile();
        formWriter.write(formPage);
        formWriter.flush();
        formWriter.close();

        Document doc2 = Jsoup.parse(formFile, "UTF-8", "http://www.facebook.com");
        Elements entry = doc2.select("textarea[name^=entry]");
        viewFormEntry = entry.attr("name");

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    dataFile = new File("DataFile");
    try {
        dataFile.createNewFile();
        dfWriter = new PrintWriter(dataFile);
        dfWriter.println(title);
        dfWriter.println();
        dfWriter.println(imgSource);
        dfWriter.println();
        dfWriter.println(viewFormLink);
        dfWriter.println();
        dfWriter.println(viewFormEntry);
        dfWriter.println();
        dfWriter.println(formResponse);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(dataFile);
        byte [] dataArray = new byte [fis.available()];
        while (fis.read() != -1) {
            data = new String(dataArray);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return data;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
    dataBundle.putString("mydata", result);

    Intent intent = new Intent(OpeningActivity.this, Main.class);
    intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
}
```

I changed the code a bit. I am now returning the data string variable in my doInBackground. I have added the internet permission in the manifest file.
I am still getting the same error. Here is my error log below, just for convenience:

```
05-27 10:36:25.995: E/AndroidRuntime(741): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
05-27 10:36:25.995: E/AndroidRuntime(741): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-27 10:36:25.995: E/AndroidRuntime(741):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
05-27 10:36:25.995: E/AndroidRuntime(741):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
05-27 10:36:25.995: E/AndroidRuntime(741):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
05-27 10:36:25.995: E/AndroidRuntime(741):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
05-27 10:36:25.995: E/AndroidRuntime(741):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-27 10:36:25.995: E/AndroidRuntime(741):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-27 10:36:25.995: E/AndroidRuntime(741):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-27 10:36:25.995: E/AndroidRuntime(741):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-27 10:36:25.995: E/AndroidRuntime(741): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-27 10:36:25.995: E/AndroidRuntime(741):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.determineTarget(AbstractHttpClient.java:496)
05-27 10:36:25.995: E/AndroidRuntime(741):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:626)
05-27 10:36:25.995: E/AndroidRuntime(741):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)
05-27 10:36:25.995: E/AndroidRuntime(741):  at org.social.myconfessions.OpeningActivity$getWebPage.doInBackground(OpeningActivity.java:68)
05-27 10:36:25.995: E/AndroidRuntime(741):  at org.social.myconfessions.OpeningActivity$getWebPage.doInBackground(OpeningActivity.java:1)
05-27 10:36:25.995: E/AndroidRuntime(741):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-27 10:36:25.995: E/AndroidRuntime(741):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-27 10:36:25.995: E/AndroidRuntime(741):  ... 4 more
```

Comment: provide the full error log

Comment: also why do you return null if you need to use "result" inside the onPostExecute? Do you the INTERNET permission?

Comment: The value that you return from your doInBackground is the value that you will get as a parameter in onPostExecute (in this case, String result)
Try to fix this and see if it's going better.

Comment: What is line 68 of your activity?

Comment: String htmlPage = urlClient.execute(getHtml, resHandler);

Comment: @user2328121 Put a debug point before that line and check what is null.

Comment: sorry, im kinda new to the whole java, android thing... could you please explain with code. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify any variables on these initalization

```
DefaultHttpClient urlClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet getHtml = new HttpGet();
ResponseHandler<String> resHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
```

The `String htmlPage = urlClient.execute(getHtml, resHandler);` does not have any value to return with empty "new" variables;

Try this :

```
DefaultHttpClient urlClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet getHtml = new HttpGet(PAGE_URL);
ResponseHandler<String> resHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
```

**P.S** : If you want to show a debug message/logcat message try using

`Log.d("String Identifier", String_Variable);`

for example if you want to output the content of string variable `htmlPage`, do this :

`Log.d("htmlPage", htmlPage);`

Comment: Thanks reidzeibel! It was a silly mistake! PS> Thank you for the lod debugging messages! They will help me out a lot in the future! I am now getting a new error: @java line:76. 'Java.net.IOException. Read-only file system'. I don't know what that means. pls help. Thanks

Comment: My line 76 is: confessionsPage.createNewFile();

Comment: I think you need to specify the file path, because Android File System is a little bit more complex, you should specify the File like this : `new File(getApplicationContext.getFilesDir(), "filename");`

Comment: I am testing this on my emulator FYI

Comment: Try reading this post about creating File inside android Emulator ^^ --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634626/create-file-in-android-emulator

Comment: Should i do this with all the files that i create?

Comment: If you want to create a file in emulator, then yes. If it is tested on real device though, the 

`new File(getApplicationContext.getFilesDir(), "filename");` is enough.

also, using `getApplicationContext.getFilesDir()` is a good practice to make sure that your file is easy to access :D

Comment: what about writing to the internal storage in the emulator?

Comment: Theoretically, it should work, but if what I suggested does not work, I guess it would be better to search the question or create new question, StackOverflow suggest to avoid long comments :D